# How this code works .html(_.template()({ }) )

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am reading source code of an application, and I saw this line of code:

```
 $('#div1').html(_.template($('#div2').html())({Id: app.Id(id)}));
```

I can understand the $('#div1').html(), but why this line of code can pass two () code blocks ? it doesn't look right. Can .html() take two () blocks?

`.html(_.template()())`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because `_.template()` returns a function then we are calling that returned function with second set of `()`

```
var fn = _.template(sometemplate);//it gives a parsed template which is a function
fn(data);//it merges the data and the template to generate the html
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called interpolation, and the correct way to use it is like

```
var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
template({name : "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

same as

```
var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!")({name : "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

http://underscorejs.org/#template